# jQuery EasyUI with CakePHP - putting .ctp or .php output in a variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, cakephp, jquery-easyui

I've created a layout with jQuery EasyUI with "west" and "center" region.

In my "west" region I have menu and in "center" region I have a content. How can I dynamically change content at "center" region when I click on a element on "west" - menu?

This works but it's not dynamical.

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#test').click(function(){
        var tpl = ' <div class="easyui-layout" fit="true" style="background:#ccc;"> <div region="east" split="true" style="width:200px;">sub center</div> <div region="center">sub center</div> </div> ';
        $('#content').empty().html(tpl).layout();
});
});
</script>
```

How can I dynamically put the output of the .php or .ctp file into "tpl" variable?

Answer (score 1):

*Hi, even if you get dynamic data using the following code:*

```
$('#test').click(function(){
 $.get(loadUrl,function(tpl) {        
      $('#content').empty().html(tpl).layout();
 });
```

*It will not parse the easyui components inside the dynamically generated content from server.*

```
var ajax_load = "<img src='img/load.gif' alt='loading...' />";  
var loadUrl = "<?php echo site_url("home/student_reg"); ?>";  

$("#test").live("click",function(){  
    $('#content').html(ajax_load).load(loadUrl);
});
```

*add the following in the server site content generator:*

```
$(function(){
   $.parser.parse();
});
```

*this will parse all the easyUI components.*